# When I connect My devices From ADB connect Wireless it will show me [Offline]

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

> ADB rejected shell command (cat /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats | grep
>   10699): closed
>
> ADB rejected shell command (cat /proc/stat): closed

when i off and on developer USB debugging It Will HelpFul For Me But temporary Any One Have permanent Idea..? I Have Redmi 3s Prime.!

[image]

Comment: restart the connection from the android

Comment: if you enable usb tethering turn off.

Comment: But it Will DisConnect After Few minutes When i run My project

Comment: and adb restart is not working for me

Comment: when i off and on developer USB debugging It Will HelpFul For Me But temporary Any One Have permanent Idea